# Run Java applications By double click

Tags: java, windows, double-click

why i can`t run my java compiled applications with double click?
my applicatins just run in cmd (java -jar: my app.jar)
plz help me

Comment: because you have errors ;) which you'd better show us.

Comment: @Bozho there may be another application associated to `.jar` extension. `Open with...` doesn't help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all the answer here are valid. But if you want a true executable file in Windows then you need to create a launcher. In windows, jar files are not executable. But exe files are. There are many tools out there than wrap all your java code around some native library. I recommend http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ I think this is what you are looking for. You can easily create executable with icons and many more features.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a batch file to run your command. This way it will work without the need to make associations to .jar files. If it is a windows app then start it with javaw.exe.

Answer (score 4):

You need to associate the .jar extension with `javaw.exe`, then no console window will be shown, when you double click the jar file

This is usually done by the JDK/JRE installer, so either you didn't install the JDK properly, or you manually changed that associaten.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Windows shortcut to your `.jar` file.

The following line could be the target of the Windows shortcut.

```
%windir%\system32\javaw.exe -Xms1m -Xmx1m -jar "C:\Program Files\Jar Directory\file.jar"
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to specify the `javaw` parameters that you want, as well as the Windows parameters (normal window, maximized, start in directory) that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign `.jar` files to be executed by `javaw.exe`. You can do that using the `Open with` dialog on a `.jar` file.

BTW, doesn't the Java installer do that for you?